# Dynamically loaded assets in Rails 4 and Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am working on a Rails 4 app in application.html.erb I have the following code

```
....
<head>
   <title>...</title>
     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
     <%= yield :head %>
     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

What this does is allows me to load certain assets depending on the page I am on. So maybe in the show template of a certain action I could do something like

```
<% content_for :head do %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "show" %>
<% end %>
```

This works great and helps me keep the page structured clean and simple. The issue I am having now is that turbolinks is completely ignoring these assets and not even loading them when I click on a next link. I have looked around but cant seem to find an answer to this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, try to add  `data-turbolinks-track` into your stylesheet tag

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because [turbolinks does not replace the `<head>` element](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks):

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and **replaces only the body and the title in the head**. Think CGI vs persistent process.

As such, any changes to the `<head>` element will be ignored.